# Docker microservices, how to manage keys and certificates

Tags: docker, authentication, ssl, certificate, microservices

We are building docker-compose based development environment of java micro services. I'm struggling with the logistics of key management and trusted certificate deployment during automated build of the environment.

So far the build process produces three images, each of which has an unique SSL key pair generated in the Java key store, and the corresponding self-signed public certificate exported on the images file system.

But how I automatically deploy those trusted certificates from the image on other components (distinct images) during the build / bootstrap of the environment?

Is there some good patterns for certificate management in dockerized micro services environment?